# Is it possible to check if a page is scheduled for publishing?

Tags: event-receivers, publishing-page, schedule

I can create a ScheduledItem in an event receiver, but how do I check if a list item is scheduled?

What I've tried:

IsScheduledItem method (ScheduledItem class) - but this method: "...confirms that the SPListItem is a member of a document library that supports scheduling, and that it has start and end dates, which are required for scheduling," which is obviously no good.

Comment: your question title says, if a "page is scheduled" however explanation says "Item is scheduled", sorry but bit confused :S

Comment: The ListItem in question is a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the item is scheduled you could see the approval Status as
>   "Scheduled".

Taken from this [Post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-schedule-an-item-in-sharepoint-2010/)

> There are two ways to check for the approval status of an item as well
>   as some interesting ways about how they worked.
>
> The first option to use if (item.HasPublishedVersion) where item is an
>   SPListItem. The second option is to use if
>   (item.ModerationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
>   again, where item is an SPListItem. The second option obviously gives
>   you a little more flexibility since you can choose more than just
>   approved when checking the status type. However, for the purpose of
>   this post, we are going to just focused on approved items.

above text is taken from this [Post](http://www.sharepointben.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=7e8748f0-6f9b-42ca-ab37-6f50b1f81797&ID=601&Web=d3daed67-a8ed-42ee-813d-b8f2790bbe38)

Hope it helped :) !

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, a big help towards helpin me understand it all. But unforunately I'm doing all this on a CheckedIn event receiver and it still seems to be at the 'draft' stage by the time I evaluation it's version. Plus, at the point I'm running my code HasPublishedVersion is false.